# Cannot run MongoDB on Windows XP

Tags: mongodb, windows-xp

I downloaded MongoDB (32 bit) zip and want to run server. But when I run mongod.exe, my system says something like this:

> mongod.exe is not Win32 application

I have Windows XP 32 bit. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downloading older MongoDB release